# Possible InvalidOperationException when working with Nullable DateTime in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have some variable defined like this:

```
DateTime? tempDateTime;
```

and also I have a query like this:

```
var recordWithMinDatetime =
    locatedContracts.Where(t => t.OriginalDate.HasValue)
        .OrderBy(t => t.OriginalDate.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (recordWithMinDatetime != null)
        tempDateTime = recordWithMinDatetime.OriginalDate.Value;
```

But in the `IDE` when I hover over the last assignment, it says **"Possible InvalidOperationException"**

I have `ReSharper` installed too, so not sure if it is from R# or VS IDE but still something I should concern about I think but I don't understand what is it I have done wrong or non-safe code that it gives me this hint?

Comment: Resharper probably can't work out that OriginalDate has been checked for nullability in the query. It should be safe to tell Resharper to ignore this just the once ("disable with comment").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's likely a R# error. I would ignore it. You've ensured that `OriginalDate.Value` won't throw an exception by checking `HasValue` in your LINQ query.

R# is trying to be helpful, and probably expects a check like this:

```
if (recordWithMinDatetime != null && recordWithMinDatetime.OriginalDate.HasValue)
    tempDateTime = recordWithMinDatetime.OriginalDate.Value;
```

But in your case, this check is redundant.